# How to merge vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices

I followed a turtoriel on how to model a body. Now im stuck at the hand,it says i need to select the two vertices and select merge at center but nothing changes[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're selecting a vertex from two separate objects.  Cube.005 and Cube.006 in the Outliner.  They must be joined in *Object Mode* before you will be able to merge these verts.